# Is it possible to query a mySQL Database using Optgroup?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

For example, say I have the following code:

```
Choose a city:
<select name="city">
  <optgroup label="East Coast Cities">
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="Atlanta">Atlanta</option>
    <option value="Miami">Miami</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="West Coast Cities"> 
    <option value="Las Vegas">Las Vegas</option> 
    <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option> 
    <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option> 
  </optgroup> 
</select>
```

This will give me the correct drop down menu.. now.. say that each value is a also a value in my mySQL database. So for example, i have a table in my DB which also has these cities which is connected to a 900 row table with different people, each living in ONE of these cities.. What i would like to do is have it so that when someone selects a category it only searches for the people living in that city based on other specifications.. This is what I have in mind so far for the php file i'll use:

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("server","username","password","Database");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());
  }

$city_query = $_POST['city'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name, address, city_name
FROM (People INNER JOIN City ON People.city_name = City.city_name) 
WHERE city_name = $city_query"); 

 //print out table using echo

mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

I hope this is fairly clear. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: isent `WHERE city_name = $city_query` doing just that?

Comment: Ideally it should be, but it isn't , im not sure why. I don't know if optgroup makes CITY equal to whatever the person selects. So if the person selects NEW YORK, i dunno if CITY then equals NEW YORK

Comment: optgroup has noting to do with it

Comment: Wanna expand on that?

Comment: Sure, ok. That's fine.. but it needs to be passed BASED on what's chosen in the optgroup, doesn't it? What im asking is, is what is selected in the html code being passed to the PHP code properly? So if i select New York will $city_query = New York?

Comment: You are missing some inverted commas. I think that's all.

Comment: `echo` would answer that, so why are you asking us?

Comment: Because it does not work for whatever reason. I've echo'ed the crap out of it. I wouldn't be posting here if i hadn't tested it first.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What does your final SQL query look like?

Comment: Sorry just returned. Basically the problem comes in with the fact that I can't submit the query. I try using form action but i get a blank page. Like i said, im also not sure that opgroup makes my choice equal to 'city', i can't prove this currently because i need to PRODUCE a table first.. ive tried echo and all kinds of things. I think my logic is off a bit.